# Running weaviate with a custom contextionary

Tags: weaviate

I want to run weaviate with my own custom contextionary. I already have a trained Glove embedding, can I use it as is or does it need anything specific to be able to use it in weaviate? And do you also support other models like Fasttext?

I read the documentation that describes to start weaviate with a custom contextionary using "docker build -t my-weaviate-image --build-arg CONTEXTIONARY_LOC ." But not sure if I have all the files needed

Comment: The Contextionary itself is not only trained on GloVe and it comes with many other sources. You probably don't need to retrain it and the open-source version should be good enough. Do you have any words you are struggling with the open-source C11y?

Comment: Additionally, it is not "just" GloVe, it is part of the training mechanism.